# Process stops immediately after start

Tags: c#, python, linux, process, monodevelop

Hope you can help me. I'm coding on a Raspberry Pi with MonoDevelop.

I want to execute a python script with C# and read from it.

```
class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "sudo";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "python gpio.py";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }

    private static void OutputHandler(Object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
    }
}
```

While Debugging i can see that the Process has exited
[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vddMn.png)

But in the TaskManager i can see, that the process is still running.
Also the script controls the gpio pins. And the script controlls the pins (Led on/off), even if the "Process has exited" . But I dont get anything from redirectOutput.

Why does the Process immediately quits after starting (the script has a while true. it shouldn't stop)? Is this the right way to execute a script?
If I execute the Python script from the terminal, it works fine. It shouldn't be an error with the script. 
If I start a process e.g. FileName "libreoffice", it works too.

The script is located in the project folder in "/bin/Debug/" (the folder)
Permissions for execution are set for anyone.

Thanks,
Greetings

Comment: I think the problem is because sudo, try to run the C# program already sudo'ed and then use python as the filename and gpio.py as the parameters. But a final recomendation, instead of using Python to control the gpio's use directly C#, take a look at this: https://github.com/gusmanb/BCM2835Managed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gusman said, the problem was the sudo. And as recommended i am using now the [DLL](https://github.com/cypherkey/RaspberryPi.Net) to access the GPIO Pins. Even if the Raspberry Pi is not fully supported.